# Renamed value in index of dataframe, then sort_index() throws an error on the value pre renaming

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The below code produces a graph from some pivot tabled data. Where the pivot table data after I have renamed the value '<-24' in the index to 'less' is as in this image:
[Pivot Table Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldJPJ.png)

Not all the code is included as shown by the ...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import openpyxl
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from openpyxl import load_workbook

...

# Creating the pivot table for a count of ship_id per hours_diff_last_ais_and_last_processed_grouped
HoursDiffLastAisProcessPivotTable = pd.pivot_table(todays_df, index=["hours_diff_last_ais_and_last_processed_grouped"], values=['ship_id'], aggfunc='count', fill_value='')


HoursDiffLastAisProcessPivotTable = HoursDiffLastAisProcessPivotTable[HoursDiffLastAisProcessPivotTable.index != 'nan']
HoursDiffLastAisProcessPivotTable.rename(index={'<-24': 'less'}, inplace=True)


# Set the sheet name and then use the function to output data into excel
hours_diff_sheet_name = 'Hours diff last AIS and Proces'
output_data_to_excel(today_hours_diff_data_file, hours_diff_sheet_name, HoursDiffLastAisProcessPivotTable)


# Creating a bar chart for the data in the pivot table
HoursDiffLastAisProcessGraph = HoursDiffLastAisProcessPivotTable.plot.bar(width=0.5)
plt.legend([todays_date], bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.2), loc='center', borderaxespad=0., fontsize='x-small')
plt.xlabel('Hours')
plt.ylabel('Number of Ships')
plt.title('Hours diff between last AIS and last process Live or Launched')
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.rcParams.update({'axes.spines.top': False, 'axes.spines.right': False})
graph_path_file = new_last_processed_dir_name + '/Hours diff last AIS and Process Graph.png'
plt.savefig(graph_path_file, bbox_inches='tight')
```

This produces a graph that looks like the following:
[Example Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtsJz.png)

However I want to sort the data from largest number to smallest from left to right along the x-axis, with the '<-24' group at the far right of the x-axis. I've tried to do this with the following code
`HoursDiffLastAisProcessPivotTable.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)` after where I used the .rename()

Is there a way for me to sort the data from largest to smallest, where the group '<-24' is counted as smallest? (so it shows on the far right of the x-axis)

I currently get the following error:

```
  File "C:/Users/Michael Callum/MyPythonScripts/PivotTable1.py", line 71, in <module>
    HoursDiffLastAisProcessPivotTable.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)
  File "C:\Users\Michael Callum\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5452, in sort_index
    indexer = nargsort(
  File "C:\Users\Michael Callum\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\sorting.py", line 308, in nargsort
    indexer = non_nan_idx[non_nans.argsort(kind=kind)]
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you can't sort with a mix of strings and ints. You can change your string value to a low int to sort then change it back as a workaround.

One way this can be accomplished with a (somewhat ugly but functional) double rename, but note that you have to assign it to a new variable, because using `inplace=True` breaks the method chaining since doing any in place causes the method to `return None`

`hourdiffpivot=HoursDiffLastAisProcessPivotTable.rename({'less':-999}).sort_index(ascending=False).rename({-999:'less'})`

Then you can just reassign the variable name to the newly created object

`HoursDiffLastAisProcessPivotTable=hourdiffpivot`